# Barcode Reader Library Capable to Read Codes with Special Designs

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I used zxing in my many projects where my apps were scanning simple QR Codes. However today I got some requirement of client to scan special design QR Codes Like following.

[image]

I found That zxing can't scan these types of codes. However another application on playstore named QR Code Reader by Scan, Inc. [App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.scan.android.client) can scan these codes as well. Can some tell me that which library is used by this application? or Which library can scan these types of codes?

Comment: It works for me with zxing app from Google Play

Comment: @ssasa I updated Image. This is not scannable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Android Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview)?

> The Barcode API detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.
>
> It reads the following barcode formats:
>
> - 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
> - 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC
>
> It automatically parses QR Codes, Data Matrix, PDF-417, and Aztec values [...]